# Why can't internal destructuring be done using rest when object destructuring in JavaScript?

Tags: destructuring

I cannot use it like this.

```
const { a, ...{ b } } = { a: 1, b: 2 };
```

I wonder what's the reason? I found this on mdn but I didn't fully understand it.

"On the other hand, object destructuring can only have an identifier as the rest property."

This use is allowed in arrays.

```
const [a, b, ...[c, d, ...[e, f]]] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
```

Why can't I use it like this?